# Plotting price values of an indicator to the right scale?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I can't get the lines in this code to show their price values on the left scale. How to plot price values to the left scale? I would appreciate your help. [value on a price scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE5NA.png)

```
//@version=5
indicator("Lines", overlay=true, scale=scale.left)
base = input.float(title="Base Value", defval=0.7162,  step=0.0001)
lineChoice = input.string(title="Buy/Sell", defval = "Buy", options = ["Buy", "Sell", "Buy&Sell"])

if (lineChoice == "Buy")
    a = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base, extend=extend.both, color=color.aqua, style=line.style_solid, width=1)
    b = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 1.004, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 1.004, extend=extend.both, color=color.aqua, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
    c = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 1.01, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 1.01, extend=extend.both, color=color.aqua, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)
    d = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 1.02, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 1.02, extend=extend.both, color=color.aqua, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)
    e = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 1.03, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 1.03, extend=extend.both, color=color.aqua, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)
else
    na
if (lineChoice == "Sell")
    f = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base, extend=extend.both, color=color.purple, style=line.style_solid, width=1)
    g = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 0.996, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 0.996, extend=extend.both, color=color.purple, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
    h = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 0.99, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 0.99, extend=extend.both, color=color.purple, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)
    i = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 0.98, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 0.98, extend=extend.both, color=color.purple, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)
    j = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 0.97, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 0.97, extend=extend.both, color=color.purple, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)
else
    na
if (lineChoice == "Buy&Sell")
    a = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base, extend=extend.both, color=color.aqua, style=line.style_solid, width=1)
    b = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 1.004, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 1.004, extend=extend.both, color=color.aqua, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
    c = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 1.01, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 1.01, extend=extend.both, color=color.aqua, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)
    d = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 1.02, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 1.02, extend=extend.both, color=color.aqua, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)
    e = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 1.03, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 1.03, extend=extend.both, color=color.aqua, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)
    g = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 0.996, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 0.996, extend=extend.both, color=color.purple, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
    h = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 0.99, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 0.99, extend=extend.both, color=color.purple, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)
    i = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 0.98, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 0.98, extend=extend.both, color=color.purple, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)
    j = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=base * 0.97, x2=bar_index[1], y2=base * 0.97, extend=extend.both, color=color.purple, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)
else
    na
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tag the language your code is written in.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to place a label on the scale from the line.new() drawing objects, only plot()s are labeled.

You can use the standard plots instead with a trackprice= argument:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Lines", overlay=true, scale=scale.left)
base = input.float(title="Base Value", defval=0.7162,  step=0.0001)
lineChoice = input.string(title="Buy/Sell", defval = "Buy", options = ["Buy", "Sell", "Buy&Sell"])

plot(base, 'Base', trackprice = true )
plot(lineChoice == "Buy"  or lineChoice == "Buy&Sell"? base * 1.004 : na, 'Base * 1.004', color.aqua,   trackprice = true)
plot(lineChoice == "Buy"  or lineChoice == "Buy&Sell"? base * 1.01 : na,  'Base * 1.01',  color.aqua,   trackprice = true)
plot(lineChoice == "Buy"  or lineChoice == "Buy&Sell"? base * 1.02 : na,  'Base * 1.02',  color.aqua,   trackprice = true)
plot(lineChoice == "Buy"  or lineChoice == "Buy&Sell"? base * 1.03 : na,  'Base * 1.03',  color.aqua,   trackprice = true)
plot(lineChoice == "Sell" or lineChoice == "Buy&Sell"? base * 0.996 : na, 'Base * 0.996', color.purple, trackprice = true)
plot(lineChoice == "Sell" or lineChoice == "Buy&Sell"? base * 0.99 : na,  'Base * 0.99',  color.purple, trackprice = true)
plot(lineChoice == "Sell" or lineChoice == "Buy&Sell"? base * 0.98 : na,  'Base * 0.98',  color.purple, trackprice = true)
plot(lineChoice == "Sell" or lineChoice == "Buy&Sell"? base * 0.97 : na,  'Base * 0.97',  color.purple, trackprice = true)
```

[image]